# How to solve equation to find function inverse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation is $f(x) = 2^{x-3}$

I know you switch the $x$ and $y$ and then solve for $y$, giving $x = 2^{y-3}$, but I'm not sure how to solve the equation...?

Thanks in advance!

And yes, I'm familiar with logarithms and I know that you would take the log of each side, giving $\ln x = \ln 2^{y-3}$, but how do I solve after that?

Comment: Are you familiar with logarithms?

Comment: What is just changing $x$ and $y$? What do you get inter-changing $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, but how does that help?

Comment: Use the fact that $log_b(b^{f(x)}) = f(x)$. In your case, this means that $log_2(2^{x-3}) = x-3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the inverse of $f(x) = 2^{x - 3}$, first interchange $x$ and $y$ to obtain

$$x = 2^{y - 3}$$

If we take the logarithm base $2$ of each side, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\log_2 x & = y - 3\\
\log_2 x + 3 & = y
\end{align*}

The inverse is $f^{-1}(x) = \log_2 x + 3$.

Check:
\begin{align*}
(f^{-1} \circ f)(x) & = f^{-1}(2^{x - 3})\\
                    & = \log_2 2^{x - 3} + 3\\
                    & = x - 3 + 3\\
                    & = x
\end{align*}
for each $x$ in the domain of $f$, which is the set of all real numbers.

\begin{align*}
(f \circ f^{-1})(x) & = f(\log_2 x + 3)\\
                    & = 2^{\log_2 x + 3 - 3}\\
                    & = 2^{\log_2 x}\\
                    & = x
\end{align*}
for each $x$ in the domain of $f^{-1}$, which is the set of all positive real numbers.

If you prefer to work with natural logarithms, then

\begin{align*}
\ln x & = \ln 2^{y - 3}\\
\ln x & = (y - 3)\ln 2\\
\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2} & = y - 3\\
\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2} + 3 & = y
\end{align*}

Thus, the inverse is $f^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{\ln x}{\ln 2} + 3$.  Note that the two answers are equivalent since

$$\log_2 x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}$$

by the Change of Base Formula.

Answer (score 2):

Just use logarithms:
$$
  x = 2^y-3\iff x+3 = 2^y\iff y = \log_2(x+3)
$$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but it's y = 2^(x-3)

Comment: @ZanderMaitland: then it's even easier, just take $\log_2$ of both sides and then add 3 to the both sides.

Comment: How would that help? Then it would be log y + 3 = log 2 ^ (y-3) + 3...

Comment: @ZanderMaitland: there shall be $x$ somewhere. Also, that is $\log_2 (2^{x-3})$?